# BBCODE IMG TAG variations with REGEX

Tags: php, regex, image, tags, bbcode

I need to convert BBCODE IMG TAG to HTML.
The problem is: the IMG TAG has multiple variations.

```
[img]img_patch[/img]
[img=200x150]img_patch[/img]
[img width=200 height=150]img_patch[/img]
[img=width=200xheight=150]img_patch[/img]
[img width=200]img_patch[/img]
```

This regex below cover the First one and the Second one.

```
'#\[img](.+)\[/img]#Usi',
'#\[img=?(\d+)?x?(\d+)?\](.*?)\[/img\]#Usi',
```

I need help with the other variations or turning all the variations in an unique REGEX.
I realy apreciate your help!

Comment: Anyone? Please help!

Answer (score 1):

This should cover all cases:

```
<?php

$data = <<<DATA
[img]img_patch[/img]
[img=200x150]img_patch[/img]
[img width=200 height=150]img_patch[/img]
[img=width=200xheight=150]img_patch[/img]
[img width=200]img_patch[/img]
DATA;

$regex = '~
          (?P<tag>\[img[^][]*\])
          (?P<src>.+?)
          \[/img]
          ~x';

$inner = '~\b(?P<key>width|height)?=(?P<value>[^\s\]]+)~';
$values = '~\d+~';

$data = preg_replace_callback($regex,
    function($match) use($inner, $values) {
        $attr = [];
        preg_match_all($inner, $match['tag'], $attributes, PREG_SET_ORDER);
        foreach($attributes as $attribute) {
            if (!empty($attribute["key"])) $attr[$attribute["key"]] = $attribute["value"];
            else {
                preg_match_all($values, $attribute["value"], $width_height);
                list($attr["width"], $attr["height"]) = array($width_height[0][0], $width_height[0][1]);
            }
        }

        // do the actual replacement here
        $attr["src"] = $match["src"];
        $ret = "<img";
        foreach ($attr as $key => $value) $ret .= " $key='$value'";
        $ret .= '>';

        return $ret; 
    },
    $data);

echo $data;
?>
```

And yields

```
<img src='img_patch'>
<img height='150' width='200' src='img_patch'>
<img width='200' height='150' src='img_patch'>
<img height='150' width='200' src='img_patch'>
<img width='200' src='img_patch'>
```

The code uses a multi-step-approach: first matching all the tags, then analyzing the attributes. In the end, the new string is formed.

See [**a demo on ideone.com**](https://ideone.com/rptUJW).

---

Note: As opposed to your (nickname) son, now you actually do know something, don't you?

Answer (score 0):

Hey Jan I really thank you for your help! Yes, I don't know everything but I do know something. Actually I have created the following REGEX and works fine and covers all IMG TAGs:

```
'#\[img=(.+)\]#Usi',
'#\[img=+(\d+)x+(\d+)\](.+)\[/img\]#Usi',
'#\[img[\s|=]+[width=]+([0-9]+)?[\s|x]+[height=]+([0-9]+)\](.+)\[/img\]#Usi',
'#\[img[\s]+[width=]+([0-9]+)\](.+)\[/img\]#Usi',
```

I hope this post may help others on their own projects!